# Передача данных в элемент управления ASP.NET C Sharp

Tags: c#, asp.net

Приветствую! Есть код.

```
public void PortEvent(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    Byte[] bytes = new Byte[256];
    int i = 0;

    try
    {
        i = portTest.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    }
    catch (Exception errorCode)
    {
        return;
    }
    if (i > 0)
    {
        TextBox1.Text = BitConverter.ToString(bytes, 0, i);
        if (bytes[0] == 0x30)
        {
            Panel1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        }
        else
        {
            Panel1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
        }

    }

}
```

Нормально доходит до этого места `Panel1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;`
но визуально на страничке ничего не происходит? Как передать данные? Спасибо.

Comment: Если сделать так, то окрашивается в нужный цвет.
        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Panel1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        }

Comment: А откуда в приходите в PortEvent?

Comment: Это событие ComPorta. Всё работает, даже данные из Com порта записываются в ящик(в отладчике смотрю), но на экране этого не видно

Comment: Ниоткуда не прихожу) это просто событие. Есть что то в буфере порта - вызывается эта подпрограмма

Comment: asp.net и comport?

Comment: Ну да. я это никогда не делал, решил попробовать. очень надо

Comment: Нужно просто вставить цифры в ящик. думаю, есть какое то решение

Comment: Я просто не понимаю как это asp? Оно же по запросу работает....

Answer (score 1):

У думаю, Вам надо на клиенте сделать какой-нибудь таймер, который бы через Web-сервис проверял, не пришли ли данные от COM-порта. И если они пришли, обрабатывать их и перезагружать страницу. Писать это, понятное дело, на `JavaScript` придётся.

Ещё попробуйте посмотреть в сторону `Silverlight`. Я не знаю, почему Вы выбрали [ASP.NET](http://ASP.NET) для такой задачи, нормально и красиво её на этой платформе не решить, потому как это распределённая архитектура, да ещё и с пассивным сервером.

Answer (score 0):

если это не asp попробуйте сделать:

```
Invoke(new Action(()=>{Panel1.BackColor = Colors.Red; Panel1.Invalidate();}));
```

Comment: Попробую. Но программа работает под управлением ASP.

Comment: А как это?!? Откуда там события то от ком порта возьмутся????

Comment: Могу прислать проект.

Comment: Лучше ссылку дайте, было бы интересно.

Comment: Ссылки нет. да собственно это почти и весь проект. там только еще конфигурация Com порта и все. и textBox

Comment: Я пока panel убрал